# Power BI - Rename table B by entries in column 1 of table A

Tags: powerbi, m

I have two text files. One contains the header names, the other contains the data.

1. Import the header names text file to table A. It has n rows, which hold the names of the data columns.
2. Import the n columns of data in the data text file to table B.
3. Can I rename the n columns in table B with the names stored in the n rows of table A?

My procedural brain imagines:

1. for each row number i in table A
2. rename column i using something similar to the line of DAX code below

   ```
   #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"Column" & [Index], "Table_A_Column_1_Row_i_Value"}})
   ```

Comment: Can't you just transpose the column with the columnnames in table A, promote them to headers and then append the data in Table B? If that doesn't work for you, then please show us what both tables look like.

Comment: Worked a charm Marco. Just needed to wait to promote headers after the append.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Table.ColumnNames` to generate a list of old columns names from `TableB`

Use `Table.ToList` to generate a list of new column names from `TableA`

Use `List.Zip` to create a list of lists, containing the old and new column names

Use these arguments in `Table.RenameColumns`:

```
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(
    TableB,
    List.Zip(
        {Table.ColumnNames(TableB), Table.ToList(TableA)}
    )
)
```

As an aside, this is not DAX - this is M.

Comment: Thanks Olly. Thanks for the answer. I will try it even though Marco's comment worked almost as well, except It lost the data type setting of the data. I need to experiment with M anyway for when I try to implement a fourth difference calculation on a few columns.

Comment: Now I play with it, it opens better ways to do a few more things. Thanks.